# MobileFirst 6.3 invoking backend service created adapter procedure

Tags: soap, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am having a hard time working out how to invoke my adapter which MobileFirst has created for me using the Discover Back End Service feature.

I created my adapter, and I am not using the following code to try and call it:

```
function callService(){
    alert("Calling into Backend");
    var options = {
            onSuccess : loadSuccess,
            onFailure : loadFailure,
            invocationContext: {}
        };

    var params = {"itemRequiredReference":10};

    var invocationData = {
            adapter : 'SoapAdapter1',
            procedure : 'inquireSingleService_inquireSingle',
            parameters : [params]
        };

    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, options);
}
```

But this does not seem to work. I get the error :

```
{"status":200,"invocationContext":{},"invocationResult":{"statusCode":500,"errors":[],"isSuccessful":true,"Envelope":{"SOAP-ENV":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/","Body":{"Fault":{"":"","detail":{"CICSFault":{"CDATA":"DFHPI1010 02/02/2015 22:11:37 GENAPPA1 CPIH 00518 XML generation failed. A conversion error (INVALID_ZONED_DEC) occurred when converting field itemReferenceNumber for WEBSERVICE inquireSingleWrapper.","xmlns":"http://www.ibm.com/software/htp/cics/WSFault"}},"faultcode":"SOAP-ENV:Server","faultstring":"Conversion to SOAP failed"}},"soap":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"},"statusReason":"Internal Server Error","responseHeaders":{"Date":"Mon, 02 Feb 2015 22:11:37 GMT","Content-Length":"000000000000608","Content-Type":"text/xml; charset=UTF-8","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Server":"IBM_CICS_Transaction_Server/5.2.0(zOS)"},"warnings":[],"responseTime":578,"totalTime":581,"info":[]}}
```

The generated adapter code looks like this :

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Generated code - Do not edit                                                                                  //
//                                                                                                               //
// This is a SOAP adapter that was auto-generated by Worklight for invocation of specific SOAP-based services.   //
// The adapter may invoke more than one service as long as they are all from the same enpdpoint (server host).   //
// Each adapter procedure matches a single operation for the same endpoint server and accepts:                   //
//   params  - Serialized JSON representation of the XML-based SOAP body to be sent to the service               //
//   headers - Custom HTTP headers to be specified when invoking the remote service. It is a JSON object with    //
//             the headers names and values. E.g. { 'name1' : 'value1', 'name2' : 'value2' }                     //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function inquireSingleService_inquireSingle(params, headers){
    var soapEnvNS = '';
    // The value of 'soapEnvNS' was set based on the version of the SOAP to be used (i.e. 1.1 or 1.2).
    soapEnvNS = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';

    // The following mappings object was autogenerated from the XML schema of the input message to the service.
    // It is being used to support a params JSON when invoking this procedure that don't specify the namespace
    // prefix nor specifying whether a property is attribute or not.
    // 
    // The 'roots' object has the list of message parts within the invocation SOAP message. Each entry has a
    // mapping between the root element name and its namespace prefix and type.
    // Each root object may define 'nsPrefix' and 'type'. Both are optional - If there is no need for a NS prefix
    // then the 'nsPrefix' should not be specified. If the element is a simple type then the 'type' should not be
    // specified.
    //
    // The 'types' object has a list of types each defining the children of the type and the definition of each
    // child. If the child is a complext type, the 'type' property has a reference to the child type definition.
    // Each child object may define:
    // 'nsPrefix' (optional) - Holds the namespace prefix to be attached to the element. If there is no need for 
    //   a NS prefix then the 'nsPrefix' should not be specified. 
    // 'type' (optional) - If the element is a simple type then the 'type' should not be specified. If it is an 
    //   attribute then 'type' should have the value of '@'. Otherwise the value of 'type' is a reference to the 
    //   type definition within the 'types' object.
    var mappings = {
        roots: {
            'inquireSingleRequest': { nsPrefix: 'reqns', type: 'reqns:inquireSingleRequest' }               
        },

        types: {
            'reqns:inquireSingleRequest': {
                children: [
                    {'itemRequiredReference': { nsPrefix: 'reqns' }}    
                ]
            }
        }
    };
    var namespaces = 'xmlns:resns="http://www.exampleApp.inquireSingleResponse.com" xmlns:reqns="http://www.exampleApp.inquireSingleRequest.com" xmlns:tns="http://www.exampleApp.inquireSingleResponse.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ';
    var request = buildBody(params, namespaces, mappings, soapEnvNS);
    var soapAction = '';
    return invokeWebService(request, headers, soapAction);
}



function buildBody(params, namespaces, mappings, soapEnvNS){
    var body =
        '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="' + soapEnvNS + '">\n' +
        '<soap:Body>\n';

    var fixedParams = {};
    for (var paramName in params) {
        if (mappings['roots'][paramName]) { //There is mapping for this param
            var root = mappings['roots'][paramName];
            var name = paramName;
            if (root['nsPrefix'])
                name = root['nsPrefix'] + ':' + paramName;
            fixedParams[name] = handleMappings(params[paramName], root['type'], mappings['types']); 
        }
        else {
            fixedParams[paramName] = params[paramName];
        }
    }

    body = jsonToXml(fixedParams, body, namespaces);

    body += 
        '</soap:Body>\n' +
        '</soap:Envelope>\n';
    return body;
}

function handleMappings(jsonObj, type, mappings) {
    var fixedObj = {};
    var typeMap = mappings[type]['children']; //Get the object that defines the mappings for the specific type

    // loop through the types and see if there is an input param defined
    for(var i = 0; i < typeMap.length; i++) {
        var childType = typeMap[i];

        for(var key in childType) {
            if(jsonObj[key] !== null) { // input param exists
                var childName = key;
                if (childType[key]['nsPrefix'])
                    childName = childType[key]['nsPrefix'] + ':' + key;

                if (!childType[key]['type']) //Simple type element
                    fixedObj[childName] = jsonObj[key];
                else if (typeof jsonObj[key] === 'object' && jsonObj[key].length != undefined) { //Array of complex type elements
                    fixedObj[childName] = [];
                    for (var i=0; i<jsonObj[key].length; i++)
                        fixedObj[childName][i] = handleMappings(jsonObj[key][i], childType[key]['type'], mappings);
                }
                else if (typeof jsonObj[key] === 'object') //Complex type element
                    fixedObj[childName] = handleMappings(jsonObj[key], childType[key]['type'], mappings);
                else if (childType[key]['type'] == '@') //Attribute
                    fixedObj['@' + childName] = jsonObj[key];
            }
        }
    }

    return fixedObj;
}

function getAttributes(jsonObj) {
    var attrStr = '';
    for(var attr in jsonObj) {
        if (attr.charAt(0) == '@') {
            var val = jsonObj[attr];
            attrStr += ' ' + attr.substring(1);
            attrStr += '="' + xmlEscape(val) + '"';
        }
    }
    return attrStr;
}

function jsonToXml(jsonObj, xmlStr, namespaces) {
    var toAppend = '';
    for(var attr in jsonObj) {
        if (attr.charAt(0) != '@') {
            var val = jsonObj[attr];
            if (typeof val  === 'object'  &&  val.length != undefined) {
                for(var i=0; i<val.length; i++) {
                    toAppend += "<" + attr + getAttributes(val[i]);
                    if (namespaces != null)
                        toAppend += ' ' + namespaces;
                    toAppend += ">\n";
                    toAppend = jsonToXml(val[i], toAppend);
                    toAppend += "</" + attr + ">\n";
                }
            }
            else {
                toAppend += "<" + attr;
                if (typeof val  === 'object') {
                    toAppend += getAttributes(val);
                    if (namespaces != null)
                        toAppend += ' ' + namespaces;
                    toAppend += ">\n";
                    toAppend = jsonToXml(val, toAppend);
                }
                else {
                    toAppend += ">" + xmlEscape(val);
                }
                toAppend += "</" + attr + ">\n";
            }
        }
    }
    return xmlStr += toAppend;
}


function invokeWebService(body, headers, soapAction){
    var input = {
        method : 'post',
        returnedContentType : 'xml',
        path : '/exampleApp/inquireSingleWrapper',
        body: {
            content : body.toString(),
            contentType : 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
        }
    };
    WL.Logger.error("ANDY:"+body.toString());
    //Adding custom HTTP headers if they were provided as parameter to the procedure call
    //Always add header for SOAP action 
    headers = headers || {};
    if (soapAction != 'null')
        headers.SOAPAction = soapAction;
    input['headers'] = headers;

    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}

function xmlEscape(obj) {
    if(typeof obj !== 'string') {
        return obj;
    }
    return obj.replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
           .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
           .replace(/'/g, '&apos;')
           .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
           .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}
```

I am a little lost - the parameters parameter on the invocationData object is what needs to be fixed - but its really very unclear what mapping as a json object I am meant to be passing as a parameter. **Can somebody please show me what parameter I need to pass to set itemRequiredReference to the number 30.**

If you need the WSDL I used to generate the service this is what I used : http://we.tl/fHgRos3f4e

This is the service being invoked from soapUI @idan :
[image]

Comment: Does it work properly when using SoapUI? http://www.soapui.org/

Comment: Downloading it now - but the service does work using standard HTTP Post with soap envelopes. That is really besides the point though - this is a working service - I want to call it from within my MobileFirst project - so what incantation of a JSON object do i need to pass to the inquireSingleService_inquireSingle function - all required information should be in the question.

Comment: Idan - I attached a picture of the service being invoked successfully from soapUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I finally found a useful documentation page here :http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_invocation_generated_soap_adapter.html

and the solution was to set parameters variable to :

```
var params = {"inquireSingleRequest": {"itemRequiredReference": "10"}}

    var invocationData = {
            adapter : 'SoapAdapter1',
            procedure : 'inquireSingleService_inquireSingle',
            parameters : [params]
        };
```

This allowed it to work perfectly.